# Trying to get bytes from this encoded string (image)

Tags: .net, image, byte, decode, imagejpeg

I'm trying to get an image from a multipart-form/data in my .net core API, but I just cant figure out what encoding is being use to encrypt this image data. Basically I need to get the byte array (of the image) represented inside this string

but the image doesn't render.[image: Strying I get when reading body value]

and this is how I get this encoded string:

```
 using (Stream responseStream = resposta.GetResponseStream())
 {
  var contentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(response.ContentType);
  var boundary = HeaderUtilities.RemoveQuotes(contentType.Boundary).Value;

   for (MultipartReader smth = new(boundary, responseStream); ;)
   {
     try
     {
        MultipartSection section = await smth.ReadNextSectionAsync();

        if (section == null)
        break;

        string contentTypeFrame = section.ContentType;

        
        // Returns me the encoded string
        string bodyValue = await section.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
        if (bodyValue.ToLower().Contains("heartbeat"))
          continue;

       if (contentTypeFrame == "image/jpeg")
       {
         //Do something if it is an image
       }
    }

   catch (Exception ex) { }
  }
}
```

any ideas on how'd I try to decode this string to get the image bytes?

Comment: `section.ReadAsByteArrayAsync`

Comment: This has many mistakes. First, encoding is not encryption and the longer you think they are the same the more problems you will have. Any time you use async you should use `await`. If your contentType is JPEG then the payload is **not** a string and trying to call `ReadAsStringAsync` is not going to work. Also never use `catch (Exception ex) { }`. Ever.

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself correctly, this is an "test environment", that is why there is a catch without any handling, also I dont really use try catch, I've got a middlerware for that. 
Altho you didn't exactly tell me how'd I do it, you were right, my problem was that I was trying to get the JPEG binary data as a string. (way beyond that btw) but I figured out how to get the data properly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

after many tries I got the correct piece of code to handle getting files from "multipart/x-mixed-replace;" requests, Once you break it to the  MultiPart Section here:

```
using (var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                using (Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue
                        .Parse(request.ContentType);

                    string boundary = HeaderUtilities
                        .RemoveQuotes(contentType.Boundary).Value;

                    MultipartSection section;

                    for (MultipartReader smth = new(boundary, responseStream); ;)
                    {
                        section = await smth.ReadNextSectionAsync();

                        if (section is null) break;

                        var bytes = ConverteStreamToByteArray(section.Body);
                        
                        // Save or handle the Byte array
                    }
                }
```

**OBS:** If you're really looking for the bytes of the content, **under no circumstances** use the readasstringasync() function, it'll change the content body. (In case of images, it'll add both the content-type and content-length to the body, and you wont be able to convert it to jpg again)

You'll now only need this function I wrote to get the data out of the Section Body Stream

```
 public static byte[] ConvertStreamToByteArray(Stream stream)
        {
            stream.Position = 0; 
            // for some reason the position aways starts at the last index, So make  
            // sure to set it to 0 here

            byte[] byteArray = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new())
            {
                int bit;
                while ((bit = stream.Read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    mStream.Write(byteArray, 0, bit);
                }
                return mStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```